# тэг "a" не изменяет свой размер

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Заключаю тэг `img` в тэг `a` и вижу, что высота тэга не изменяется совсем никак!

По идее он должен принимать ширину и высоту тэга `img`, но этого не происходит. Думал, задам ширину и высоту тэгу, и не работает!

При изменении ширины и высоты тэг а их просто игнорирует ДАЖЕ с !important. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<a href=""><img src="img/2_with_shadow_++.png" alt=""></a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну не изменяется, и что?

Answer (score 3):

назначьте тегу `<a>` стиль

```
display: inline-block;
```

такие элементы как `span` и т.п. не очень любят когда в них другие объекты засовывают, поэтому приходится превращать их во что-то `div`ообразное таким стилем

Answer (score 2):

Допиши ему

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: @HamSter, опечатка - исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```